# C split pointer array and save in new var

Tags: c, pointers, variables, multidimensional-array, split

I'm very busy with splitting and saving the result for a 2d pointer array in another smaller 2d pointer array. However, I cannot get this working; only the first line matches. Can someone help me or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void print_grid(bool *grid, int n, int m){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++){
            printf("%d ", (bool)*((grid+i*n) + j));
        }        
        printf("\n"); 
    }   
}

void generate_random_values_grid(bool *grid, int n, int m){
    int i, j;    
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++){    
        for (j = 0; j<m; j++){
            int rndm = (rand() %2);  
            *((grid+i*n) + j) = rndm;     
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n=7;
    int m=5;      
    int num_procs = 3;
    int division = 2;

    bool *grid = (bool *)malloc(n*m*sizeof(bool));
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    generate_random_values_grid((bool *)grid, n, m);
    print_grid((bool *)grid, n, m);

    //Split
    printf("----Split with division: %d ---------\n", division);
    bool *division_grid = (bool *)malloc(division*m*sizeof(bool));
    memcpy((bool *)division_grid, (bool *)grid, (division*m*sizeof(bool)));
    print_grid((bool *)division_grid, division, m);   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*((grid+i*n) + j) = rndm;` shouldn't it be `*((grid+i*m) + j) = rndm;`

Comment: Yess, thats true, haha! Thanks for the note.

Comment: Problem is solved. Thread can be closed LOL. Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double loops are all wrong:

```
for (i = 0; i<n; i++){    
    for (j = 0; j<m; j++){
        int rndm = (rand() %2);  
        *((grid+i*n) + j) = rndm;     
    }
```

the 1D index computation from 2 indexes is *wrong*.

Unless `m == n`, you're multiplying `i` by `n`, so when `i == n-1` you get an offset of `n*(n-1)`. So ask you this question: what if `m = 1` and `n = 10000` ?

The proper formula is:

```
*((grid+i*m) + j) = rndm;
```

Some better ways to do this would be:

- Precompute the row offset into a row pointer: `bool *row = grid+i*m` then enter the loop, access elements with `row[j]`
- Use a real, variable-length, array instead of `malloc` in the main routine (`bool grid[n][m];` after `n` and `m` have been determined).